# how to get file from remote machine

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008-sp1

i have got a remote machine which i can access using ftp (it has static ip with userid and pass).
i am able to send file to that location using FTP through asp.net but don't know how to get that file back using asp.net through code.
actually wants 2 things using asp.net code:
1. get file from remote machine which has static ip and userid & pass.
2. after getting that file delete that file from remote machine.

please provide me solution
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got the solution:

```
Protected Sub btnDownloadFile_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
Dim myFtpWebRequest As FtpWebRequest
Dim myFtpWebResponse As FtpWebResponse
Dim myStreamWriter As StreamWriter

myFtpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create("ftp://ftp_server_name/filename.ext")

'myFtpWebRequest.Credentials = New NetworkCredential("username", "password")

myFtpWebRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile
myFtpWebRequest.UseBinary = True

myFtpWebResponse = myFtpWebRequest.GetResponse()

myStreamWriter = New StreamWriter(Server.MapPath("filename.ext"))
myStreamWriter.Write(New StreamReader(myFtpWebResponse.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd)
myStreamWriter.Close()

litResponse.Text = myFtpWebResponse.StatusDescription

myFtpWebResponse.Close()
End Sub
```

http://dotnetacademy.blogspot.com/2010/12/how-to-upload-download-delete-file.html

Answer (score 1):

Check out this page.

http://bytes.com/topic/visual-basic-net/answers/349767-retrieve-file-ftp-address